# How to get maximum width of multiline TextView in android?

Tags: android, layout, uiview, uitextview

I am new in android and facing the problem to get the maximum width of the multiline TextView.

I used `textview.getWidth()` and `textview.getMeasuredWidth()` but both gives garbage value.

I used also `textview.length()`, but retuns zero.

Please note that i have not set the maximum width of the TextView.I want to get it runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try to use `getWidth()`. If you want to do that though, you have to be careful when you call it. It only makes sense after the view hierarchy is laid out. That means that trying to check `onCreate`, `onStart` or even `onResume` will probably not get the results that you want. As an experiment, you can call it in a click handler of a button and you should see the expected value correctly being returned. I can't really say any more about where you should get it without knowing what you want to use it for.

Answer (score 1):

```
TextView_name.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(250,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

by using the above code we can set the width for textview dynamically

Comment: but i don't want to fix the width of textView.I want to use `TextView_name.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(250,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));`